# Hotkeys have changed, how can I fix this?

Tags: shortcut

So I don't know what I have done or if I have installed something. I can't remember. 
Pressing the TAB key opens this weird looking thing:
[image]

Pressing W doesn't ope the edge thing.
Those are my main concerns, and they have been killing me for a while now. I did download the blender supercharge layout, but I didn't install it directly into blender.
I don't know if this is part of any update blender has made but does anyone know how to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably if you go to Edit >>> Preferences >>>> Load Factory Preferences

[image]

Hope that Helps

Good Luck